# What is better if else or only if to return a value inside a function and why?

Tags: php, arrays, function, if-statement

Hi a am hesitant to ask this but I need some advise about this sample code and what is better between the two function below.

```
function get_product($productType){
  $product =[];

  if('available'== $productType){
    $product = array('tshirt','pants','polo'); 
  }else if('out_of_stock' == $productType){
    $product = array('short');
  }
  return $product;
}
```

or

```
function get_product($productType){
  $product = array('tshirt','pants','polo');

  if('out_of_stock' == $productType){
    $product = array('short');
  }
  return $product;
}
```

I just want to get the opinion of some programmers.Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.'* but i pick B anyway. some people would move that return inside the if

Comment: The first one informs the reader that 'available' is a possible type. And it returns an empty array if type is neither of them.
The second one returns the array of three regardless of what garbage might be in type. 
So in this special case my **opinion** would be that the first is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see both quite commonly. If they're both functionally identical and there's no performance / other reason why you'd pick a particular one over the other, then go with the most readable one, or whichever makes the most sense to you.

However, in this particular case I can point out that a [conditional ternary operator](https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators) would shorten things considerably:

```
function get_product($productType) {
    return 'out_of_stock' == $productType ?
            array('short') :
            array('tshirt','pants','polo');
}
```

Comment: you shouldn't answer questions that are going to be closed as off topic here on stack overflow

Comment: @Dagon Perhaps I'm wasting my time, but at least the OP learned something.

Comment: @Parker Thanks a lot :D

Comment: but it encourages bad questions, so is bad for the site overall.

Comment: @Dagon I think you are right. but how would beginners like OP know it, if they cant get advices from experts here in so.

Comment: the are many other great php sites. SO is not the only php site on the planet

Comment: @Dagon my only point is that we are here in so to get help and to help others.I am not arguing to your opinion since that's yours.

Comment: i like the way SO works, and this question is clearly outside its remit.